# HTTP Request in Node Server Only Works Once Upon Deployment on Heroku Instead of Upon Each Time Opening the App

Tags: node.js, http, express, heroku

A bit background: I have an Express server backend. In it, I have an axios request to fetch Twitter timeline. It gets data from Twitter, then sends a JSON to the client side. The client side GETs it and displays it in the UI.

My problem is that the HTTP request only gets fired upon deployment of the app on Heroku. When I post a new tweet, the client side doesn't show this new tweet. Only when I re-deploy the app, the new tweet shows up.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code, it's hard to figure out the exact reason. But it sounds like you're doing this twitter call when the app starts, rather than when a request is made to your node service.

You should make the call to twitter when your client side issues the GET request. So the flow might look like this.

1. Client side makes GET request to your node service
2. Your service makes the call to the twitter API
3. Your service transforms the data that has come back from Twitter and returns it as the response to the GET request.

This means it'll make a call to twitter every time you make your API call, not just once when the application starts up.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this solution! I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Could you please help me with this new problem I ran into? It should be super easy for you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690060/in-an-express-js-server-how-can-i-send-an-html-with-style-and-js-acquired-fro

Comment: @Jake.N sure, I've provided a long answer for you and moved the conversation over there, I hope that helps.