# In an Express.js server, how can I send an HTML (with style and js) acquired from a HTTP request, as a response?

Tags: node.js, express

This is an Express.js server. I'm trying to authenticate my Instagram API.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');
const ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();

//  bodyparser middleware setup
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



var instagramClientId = '123123';

app.get('/instagram', (req, res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=${instagramClientId}&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`,
      }).then((response) => {

    res.send(response.data);
    console.log(response.data);


        }).catch((e) => {
              console.log(e);
          });
});

// port set-up
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app fired up on port ${port}`);
});
```

**This is the error I got. Looks like the html file was sent just fine, but the css and js weren't executed. You can see the error messages were all about style and js not being excuted.**

[image]

**Is this because I need to enable some options in my res.send() code?**

Comment: Quick question, why are you setting the view engine to ejs then sending a .html file

Comment: The css and js can be inline in the HTML, in which case you just send the HTML and the css and js are contained with in it.  If the css and js are referred to by links, then your server has to make sure those links work so that when the browser requests the links that represent those resources, there is a server to send those resources to the browser.

Comment: I set the view engine to ejs because I thought it would fix it by using res.render(). Then I realized the file is not .ejs

Comment: Looks like problem is with the paths of .css and .js files. Can you share instagram.html file?

Comment: Good point, but my instagram.html is blank. The html we discuss here is fetched from an HTTP request to instagram API. This html file has external css and js which are not working.

Comment: I don't know what format that instagram API URL returns. If it returns HTML data buffer then before sending response data add 'res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');'   to tell that the type is HTML.

Comment: I did add res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html'); It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer two questions here, the first is what I think you're actually having problems with and the second is what would technically be the answer to this question.

**What I think your actual problem is: A misunderstanding of OAuth2.0**

Looking at your code, it looks like you're trying to get a user to authenticate with Instagram. This is great, OAuth2.0 is fantastic and a good way to authenticate at the moment, but you've got the wrong end of the stick with how to implement it. OAuth2.0 is about redirects, not proxying HTML to the user. In this case it looks like you're using axios to make a server side call to the instagram OAuth endpoint and then sending the user that HTML. What you should actually be doing is **redirecting** the user to the Instagram URL you've built.

A high level of the "dance" you go through is the following.

1. The user requests to login with instagram by pressing a button on your website.
2. You send the user to an instagram URL, that URL contains your applications token plus an "approved" redirect url. Once the user has logged in with Instagram, Instagram will redirect the user to your approved redirect url.
3. The users browser has now been redirected to a second endpoint on your server, this endpoint recieves a one-time token from Instagram. You take that token on your server side and use axios (or similar) to make a server side request to fetch some user information such as their profile. Once you have that data, you can then create a user in your the database if needed and issue a new session token to them. Along with the profile call on this, you'll also get a token given directly to you (different from the one the users browser gave you) which will allow you to make requests to the Instagram API for the privileges you requested from the user originally.

This means you have 2 endpoints on your service, the "hello, I'd like to log in with instagram, please redirect me to the instagram login page" and then "hello, instagram said I'm all good and gave me this token to prove it, you can now check with them directly" (this is the callback endpoint).

You can manage this whole process manually which is great for understanding OAuth, or you can use something like Passport.js to abstract this for you. This lets you inject your own logic in a few places and handles a lot of the back and forth dance for you. In this instance, I'd probably suggest handling it yourself to learn how it all works.

Ultimately, you are not sending the user any HTML via res.send or anything similar. Instead your first endpoint simply uses a `res.redirect(instagramUrl)`. You also thus do not make any HTTP requests during this portion, you do that on the "callback" after they've entered their username and password with Instagram.

**Technically the correct answer to this question: proxy the JS and CSS calls, but this is really bad for security!**

You're sending some HTML from a 3rd party in this case. So you will need to also allow the user access to the HTML and CSS. Security wise, this is quite iffy and you should really consider **not doing this** as it's bad practice. All of the JS and CSS links in the page are most likely relative links, meaning they're asking you for some JS and CSS which you are not hosting. Your best bet is to find these exact paths (ie: `/js/app.min.js`) and to then proxy these requests. So you'll create a new endpoint on your service which will make a request to instagrams `/js/app.min.js` and then send that back down with `res.send`.

Again, please do not do this, pretending to be another service is a really bad idea. If you need something from instagram, use OAuth2.0 to authenticate the user and then make requests using their tokens and the official instagram API.

Comment: I solved the problem and got the code. But at the next stage, the auth-token can't get fetched no matter what. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Elliot could you please answer this one more question?

Comment: @Jake.N you shouldn't really post another question in these threads if possible, your "answer" is actually further detail to the question. If you have a follow up question then I suggest creating a new stackoverflow question since this one seems so different to the original question. That way we're both abiding by the stackoverflow guidelines :) Feel free to comment here when you've moved your new question to a full question thread!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning the etiquette. Here is the new question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725524/try-to-fetch-instagram-access-token-with-all-required-params-but-still-get-an-er

Comment: @Jake.N no worries, thanks for posting the new question