# Try to fetch Instagram access token with all required params but still get an error code 400

Tags: node.js, http, express

**This is the server side code that tried to make a POST request to Instagram to get an access token**

```
app.get('/instagram/json', (req, res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
        data: {
            'client_id': instagramClientId,
            'client_secret': instagramClientSecret,
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:3000',
            'code': instagramCode
        }
      }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((e) => {
              console.log(e);
          });
});
```

**This is the error response I get. It tells me that "client_id" is required despite I clearly have provided it.**

```
 data: 
  { error_type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 400,
    error_message: 'You must provide a client_id' } } }
```

Comment: Inside your app.get, if you do console.log(instagramClientId) do you get the token that you expect? Don't post the actual token here, but we need to know if it's actually in the variable correctly.

Comment: The instagramClientId instagramClientSecret instagramCode are all successfully logged in app.get()

Comment: Here is the authentication doc https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: Hey Elliot, I solved the problem. Strangely enough, it worked when I used request instead of axios to make the HTTP POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
const insta_form = new URLSearchParams();
  insta_form.append('client_id', 'xxx');
  insta_form.append('client_secret', 'xxx');
  insta_form.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
  insta_form.append('redirect_uri', 'xxx');
  insta_form.append(
    'code',
    'xxx'
  );

    await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
      data: insta_form,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
        
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  import axios from 'axios'
  import {stringify} from 'qs'

  const response = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
    data: stringify({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID, 
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET, 
      grant_type: 'authorization_code', 
      redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL, 
      code
    }),
    headers: { "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Late, but since there's not a good answer on the web and took me a while:

You'd have to wrap your body inside a form-data before providing it to fetch-node's post.

Install form-data: `npm install --save form-data`
then:

```
const formData = require("form-data");
const insta_form = new formData();
insta_form.append("client_id", your client id);
insta_form.append("client_secret", your client secret);
insta_form.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
insta_form.append("redirect_uri", your redirect uri);
insta_form.append("code", user code);
const shortTokenRes = await fetch(
  "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: insta_form,
  }
);
```